# How do I automate unpacking the zip deployed via devops?

Tags: azure-devops

I want to set up CI/CD for a .NETCore2 api project with an Azure repository.

I want the release to be deployed to a folder on my Windows computer c:\mywebapi

I have set up a build pipeline to do the build and a release pipeline to do the deploy.

However the files land on my computer as  C:\agent_work\rX\a\myrelease\drop\WebApp.Zip of the target machine.
Where X is the release number.

How do I automate the last step of unpacking the zip to c:\mywebapi folder ?

Here is the build Yaml

```
    resources:
- repo: self
queue:
  name: Hosted VS2017
  demands: 
  - msbuild
  - visualstudio
  - vstest

#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘Parameters.solution’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972
#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘Parameters.solution’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972
#Your build pipeline references the ‘BuildPlatform’ variable, which you’ve selected to be settable at queue time. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab, and then select the option to make it settable at queue time. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865971
#Your build pipeline references the ‘BuildConfiguration’ variable, which you’ve selected to be settable at queue time. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab, and then select the option to make it settable at queue time. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865971
#Your build pipeline references the ‘BuildConfiguration’ variable, which you’ve selected to be settable at queue time. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab, and then select the option to make it settable at queue time. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865971
#Your build pipeline references the ‘BuildPlatform’ variable, which you’ve selected to be settable at queue time. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab, and then select the option to make it settable at queue time. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865971
#Your build pipeline references the ‘BuildConfiguration’ variable, which you’ve selected to be settable at queue time. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab, and then select the option to make it settable at queue time. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865971
#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘Parameters.ArtifactName’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972
steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.4.1'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 4.4.1


- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(Parameters.solution)'


- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(Parameters.solution)'

    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'

    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'

    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'


- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Test Assemblies'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\$(BuildConfiguration)\*test*.dll
     !**\obj\**

    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'

    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'


- task: PublishSymbols@2
  displayName: 'Publish symbols path'
  inputs:
    SearchPattern: '**\bin\**\*.pdb'

    PublishSymbols: false

  continueOnError: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

    ArtifactName: '$(Parameters.ArtifactName)'
```

[image: picture of build]

Comment: How did you build the project?

Comment: Hi @AndyLi-MSFT I added the build yaml to the question, does that help?

Comment: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/DevOps-Lab/DeployingtoOnPremisesServerswithVSTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to unpack the zip file to a specific folder (`c:\mywebapi` here), then you can use the `Extract Files` task in build pipeline, release pipeline is not  necessary. (Reference below screenshot, unpack to `\\172.17.16.147\TestShare\0927` in below sample)

1. Make sure your build service account has the correct permission
   (`read` and `write`) to access the specific folder (`c:\mywebapi` in
   your scenario).
2. Add a `Copy Files` task to copy the `WebApp.Zip` file to
   `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`
3. Add a `Extract Files` task to unzip the file

[image]

---

**UPDATE**:

Well, by default during the build it only generate a zip file and publish Artifact as the deploy source.

To deploy the application to a target machine or website you need to create a release pipeline and link the artifact source, then use `IIS Web App Deploy` task to deploy it. If you want to deploy as an Virtual Application, then you also need to provide the Virtual Application name...

[image]

Comment: @KirstenGreed Well, if you want to deploy the web application, you can create a release pipeline and use `IIS Web App Deploy` task to do that, see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, with the extract files step, How do I find out the IP address to use?

Comment: investigating setting up deployment groups

Comment: @KirstenGreed The IP is the target machine's IP, that's just an example to extract files to a target folder. In the example I created  a share folder on the target machine, then use the UNC path as the Destination folder...

Comment: @KirstenGreed Yeah, you can use deployment groups to deploy the application to multiple sites/target machines...

Comment: Thank you for your help. In retrospect I asked the wrong question.  I should have asked how to do an IIS Web app deploy. Unzipping on the build machine is not relevant to my purpose.  Should I delete the question or is it useful to other people?